# Rails messing up my code with "<<<<<<< HEAD"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I recently discovered that rails or some other entity is messing up my code by putting "<<<<<<< HEAD" all over the place. This is an example of what it looks like:

```
Class ExampleController
  def foo
    bar = 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
    if bar == 1
      puts "bar is one"   
    else
      puts "bar is not one"
    end
=======
  if bar == 2
    puts "bar is two"
  else
    puts "bar is not two"
  end
>>>>>>> 17fb60436a4de2e0...
  end
end
```

Anyone know why its behaving like this?

Comment: I just resisted the strong urge to hit the edit button and fix the merge conflict.

Comment: If you don't want to fix it just do ``git rebase --abort ``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, you or someone else is using GIT to version-control these sources, which is good.

Now you have to know how to resolve conflicts!

[How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

If you are the one using git, please be careful when pulling code. If there's CONFLICT written somewhere, STOP! Then use `git mergetool` or go through the list of each file concerned by a CONFLICT and edit them by hand.

Conflicting code is marked with `<<<<<<`, `========` and `>>>>>>>`. You have to merge it

Comment: I think you mean *someone* is managing those files in git, and then not using a difftool when there's a conflict.  And if the OP doesn't recognize the <<<<<<< marker, it's probably not Huub Mons messing up the merge.

Comment: Well, the worst would have been that indeed someone took unmerged code from git and just copy/pasted it and gave it to the OP. Without the .git folder. Nightmare :p

Comment: So git is the culprit eh? I will take a look at fixing those merge conflicts. Thanks!

Comment: Culprit?  git doesn't confuse people. people using git confuse people. ;^)  Good luck unconfusing whoever used git.